# The difference between n++ VS ++n in Java

Tags: java

My Java teacher said it was better to use ++n instead of n++, I am not seeing the logic behind this. Does anyone know?

Comment: I'm sure he probably said it was better to use ++n within a certain context.

Comment: Java and C and C++ and PHP and ...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java

Comment: Probably you teacher doesn't even know why. Where I live, many "programming teachers" don't have a clue.

Comment: Knowing the difference between them is important, and both have their uses. But one is not better than the other. They are simply different tools.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`++n` increments the value and returns the new one.

`n++` increments the value and returns the *old* one.

Thus, `n++` requires extra storage, as it has to keep track of the old value so it can return it after doing the increment.

I would expect the actual difference between these two to be negligible these days.  I know a lot of compilers will optimize it so they're identical if the return of `n++` isn't actually used, though I don't know of Java does that.

Comment: good explanation! in old days, this becomes significant if n is a big object and implements the ++ operator.

Comment: So their is literally no reason that `n++` is the absolute industry standard? Like, no one uses ++n, unless the code forces them to.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's true.  Most of the code I've seen in the last many years uses ++n unless they explicitly need the n++ behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Your Java teacher is (probably) refering to the fact that preincrementation is **usually** a **little tiny bit** faster than postincrementation. I'm not even sure if that's the case in Java, because I learned about that in C course.

> "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil"
>
> Donald Knuth

In everyday pracitice, I would use pre- or postincrementation basing mainly on what makes the most sense in the code.

Answer (score 4):

n++ will increment the variable prior to the operation taking place, while ++n only increments the variable after the operation.

```
So take x = 1
        y = x++
        y = 1
        x = 2 now

So take x = 1 again
        y = ++x
        y = 2
        x = 2 now
```

Comment: I think you mean x = 1; y = x++; (y == 1 && x == 2) evaluates to true, x = 1; y = ++x; (y == 2 && x == 2) evaluates to true

Comment: @Bnjmn I think you have n++ and ++n reversed in your written explanation, but your code example is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
int n = 10;
int a = n++; // a is 10
int b = n; // b is 11
int c = ++n; // c is 12
```

The difference is that the value of `++n` is `n + 1` and the value of `n++` is `n`.

Neither is better, they do the same thing. You shouldn't really rely on the difference between the two in your programs because 1.) quite a few people don't understand the difference and 2.) the same thing can be accomplished far more simply.

Comment: People who do not understand that difference should be banned from reading any code. :)

Answer (score 2):

They do different things.

Let's say n = 10. Then n++ increments n but returns 10.

++n increments n and returns 11.

Though I'm not sure which one requires more assembly instructions.

Comment: Looks like Herms and Mchl answered that question for me - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both increment and decrement operators have two forms which are very important when using the result in the current statement:

- *prefix (`++n` or `--n`) increases/decreases the value of a variable
  before it is used;*
- *postfix (`n++` or `n--`) increases/decreases the value of a variable

  after it is used.*

**let's take an example:**

- **Prefix Increment:**

> ```
> int a = 4;
> int b = ++a;
> System.out.println(a); // 5
> System.out.println(b); // 5
> ```

- **Postfix Increment**

> ```
> int a = 4;
> int b = a++;
> System.out.println(a); // 5
> System.out.println(b); // 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

++n adds one to n, then uses it;
n++ uses it then adds one.
Same applies to --.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting example that illustrates the difference:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<5; /*not incrementing here*/ ) 
            System.out.println(i++);
    }
}
```

output:
0
1
2
3
4

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<5; /*not incrementing here*/ ) 
            System.out.println(++i);
    }
}
```

output:
1
2
3
4
5

Notice that neither for-loop performs the incrementation since it does not matter there.