# Strange behaviour of the increment operators in Java?

Tags: java

I have to pieces of code:

```
int m = 4;
int result = 3 * (++m);
```

and

```
int m = 4;
int result = 3 * (m++);
```

After the execution m is 5 and result is 15 in the first case, but in the second case, m is also 5 but result is 12. Why is this the case? Shouldn't it be at least the same behaviour?

I'm specifically talking about the rules of precedence. I always thought that these rules state that parantheses have a higher precedence than unary operators. So why isn't the expression in the parantheses evaluated first?

Comment: Why do you consider this "strange"?

Comment: Why would you *expect* two completely different syntax trees to give the same result?

Comment: Because of the rules of precedence

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Comment: Not really, I'm interested why the expression in the parantheses isn't evaluated first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - because in the first case the result is 3 multiplied by "the value of `m` after it's incremented" whereas in the second case the result is 3 multiplied by "the initial value of `m` before it's incremented".

This is the normal difference between pre-increment ("increment, and the value of the expression is the value after the increment") and post-increment ("remember the original value, then increment; the value of the expression is the original one").

Comment: Thanks, but why do the rules of precedence not apply here?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: What sort of precedence are you expecting to make a difference? It's the value of the pre/post-increment expression itself which is relevant. I don't see how precedence is relevant.

Comment: I thought the rules of precendence state that parentheses have a higher precedence than unary operators. Therefore the expression in the parantheses should be evaluated first.

Comment: @Roflcoptr The fact that the expression in parantheses is evaluated first isn't relevant (or true, actually). The value of the expression `(m++)` is `m`, not `m + 1`.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: No, precedence doesn't change the evaluation order - it changes *grouping*. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx for Eric Lippert's well written blog post on this. The context is C#, but the same applies in Java. Even if this *did* affect evaluation order, it wouldn't change the result, given that the LHS of the multiplication doesn't use `m`. Why do you think it would? What would you expect the result to be, and why?

Comment: My expected result was 15 for both cases because I thought that first m is incremented in both cases since it is written in parentheses. But with your explanation it is a little bit clearer why this isn't the case.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Even if the RHS were evaluated first, the value of that expression would still be 4 for `m++`. So hopefully this question has helped you understand both precedence *and* pre/post-increment operators :)

Comment: IMHO, this kind of confusion is common enough to suggest that post-increment should be avoided, except perhaps as a standalone statement.

Comment: @Ed: I rarely use *either* except as a standalone statement (where I always use the postincrement as I find it easier to read :)

Comment: Easier to read **and** makes for better rhyming in limericks.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is when the result is assigned to m.
In the first case you have basically (not what it really does, but helps to understand)...

```
int result = 3 * (m=m+1);
```

In the second case you have

```
int result = 3 * m; m = m +1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as "increment and get" and "get and increment." For instance, see [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which has the methods [incrementAndGet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) and [getAndIncrement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of the operators:  `m++` evaluates to `m`, then increments `m`.  It's a "post-increment".  Parentheses around it don't change the fact that the operator evaluates to the variable, and also increments it afterward.