# (Potentially odd) long increment behavior?

Tags: java, long-integer, increment

I'm a bit embarrassed in asking this question, but the result of the following code snippet has me stumped:

```
System.out.println("incrementResultResponses() has been invoked!");
final long oldValue = resultResponses;
final long newValue = resultResponses++;
System.out.println("Old value = " + oldValue);
System.out.println("New value = " + newValue);
```

That outputs the following:

```
incrementResultResponses() has been invoked!
Old value = 0
New value = 0
```

Why? Would concurrency have any influence upon the result here? By the way, `resultResponses` is a `long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of the increment operators in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490790/strange-behaviour-of-the-increment-operators-in-java) - probably not the best dup, but there are literally hundreds. Please search for "[java] post-increment".

Comment: @Mat, Yes, my fault. If at all possible, I would like others to vote close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The postfix `++` operator returns the **old** value (before incrementing). You want to use prefix `++`:

```
final long oldValue = resultResponses;
final long newValue = ++resultResponses;
```

Comment: That's a bummer. For some reason, I thought assigning the postfix operator to a variable would force the operation to return the new value. :/

Comment: Why a bummer? This is just how postfix and prefix `++` are defined: postfix increments the variable and returns the old value, why prefix increments the variable and returns the new value. If you want the latter, use prefix instead of postfix `++`.

Comment: Thats crazy. I know at least 5 other languages where number++ returns the new value immediately. I was wondering why it wasnt working in Java. Thanks to you guys for learning something new

Comment: @DavidFariña really? Java has inherited this behavior from C and C++ and also in C# and JavaScript it works in the same way. So it's not a thing that is peculiar to Java.

Answer (score 3):

Because the increment increases the value **after** it was assigned (**Post-Increment**). That's exactly what `resultResponses++` is supposed to do.
If you want resultResponses to be 1, you need to use **Pre-Increment**, which is `++resultResponses`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to increment oldValue before the assignment you will have to place `++` before the variable:

```
final long newValue = ++resultResponses;
```

This means that the increment takes place before the statement is executed instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-increment-decrement-operators.php), to know how `postfix` and `prefix` work.
As mentioned in the above answers you can use this:

```
final long oldValue = resultResponses;
final long newValue = ++resultResponses;
```

Or to  make it fancier you can also use:

```
final long oldValue = resultResponses++;
final long newValue = resultResponses;
```

which will also result in the same output.