# Behaviour of pre/post increment operators in Multiplication scenarios

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Can anyone please explain me what is happening backyard to these statements?

```
int x=5;
 System.out.println((x++)*x); //Gives output as 30




int x=5;
 System.out.println((++x)*x); //Gives output as 36.
```

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley Not really a duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int x=5;
 System.out.println((x++)*x); //Gives output as 30
```

You first take x (x = 5) as an operand. Then it's incremented to 6 which is second operand.

```
int x=5;
 System.out.println((++x)*x); //Gives output as 36.
```

You first increment x by one (x = 6) and then multiply by x => 6 * 6 = 36

Comment: The underlying reason is that multiplicative operations are evaluated from left to right. If that were not the case, the result would be different.

Answer (score 4):

```
p++ means use then increment with a copy (copy is extremely local)

++p means increment and use without a copy


p++: use 5 and use incremented thing later in that line

++p: increment and use immediately
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication is left-to-right associative, so the left operand will be evaluated first, then the right operand.

Post-increment operator will evaluate to current value of the variable, and increment it right after.

Pre-increment operator will increment the variable, then evaluate to the incremented value.

```
    (x++) * x (x = 5)
--> 5 * x (increment deferred, x = 5)
--> 5 * x (increment x, x = 6)
--> 5 * 6
--> 30
```

---

```
    (++x) * x (x = 5)
--> 6 * x (x is incremented before evaluated into expression, x = 6)
--> 6 * 6
--> 36
```

I mentioned the associativity here because it will affect the final result. If the associativity of multiplication is right-to-left instead of left-to-right, then the result will be 25 and 30 for post-increment and pre-increment expression respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you understand that:

- `++x` returns `x+1` and increments `x`, while
- `x++` returns `x` and increments `x`,

the reason for the result is defined by the [Java Language Specification #15.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17)

> The multiplicative operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

So in the first case, `x++` is first evaluated, which returns 5 (it is the postfix operator) and adds 1 to `x` afterwards. Then the result of `x++` (5) is multiplied by `x` (which is now 6) ==> 30

In the second case, `++x` is first evaluated, which adds 1 to `x` and returns 6 (it is the prefix operator). Then the result of `++x` (6) is multiplied by `x` (which is now 6) ==> 36

Answer (score 3):

Post increment operators do the incrementation after the expression has been calculated.

In your first example, what is actually happening is:-

```
(x++)  * x ; // (now incremented, 6 )
// x (5) * x+1 (6)
```

In your second example, the increment happens first

```
(++x)  * x; // incremented straight away.
// x+1 (6) * x (now 6)
```