# For Loops and Logical AND + OR

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, binary, logical-operators

Why does this code take not run?

```
for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<11;j++){  

        if(i>0){
            if((staticWallLoc[i--][j]&4)>0){staticWallLoc[i][j]=staticWallLoc[i][j]|1;}
        }
        if(j<10){
            if((staticWallLoc[i][j++]&8)>0){staticWallLoc[i][j]=staticWallLoc[i][j]|2;}
        }
        if(i<10){
            if((staticWallLoc[i++][j]&1)>0){staticWallLoc[i][j]=staticWallLoc[i][j]|4;}
        }
        if(j>0){
            if((staticWallLoc[i][j--]&2)>0){staticWallLoc[i][j]=staticWallLoc[i][j]|8;}
        }

        System.out.println(i+" "+j);
    }
}
```

By the way, staticWallLoc[11][11] is a two dimensional array that has 11 indexes in each dimension (0-10).

Just wondering why my program literally cannot get passed this code.

Comment: everytime i see questions like this I'm baffled.  Have you tried using a debugger??

Comment: Those post increments and decrements of loop indexes are horrible! just use i-1 and i+1 etc as the index.

Comment: @John3136 I think you just answered the question ;)

Comment: Take a look [at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java) regarding why you should not use the i-- & i++ indexes.

Comment: It *does* run. It just never terminates,because you wrote it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `if(i > 0)`, `i` is decremented by `staticWallLoc[i--]`. Change it to `staticWallLoc[i-1]`, and do the same for `j`.

```
if(i>0){
    // Try something like this instead
    if((staticWallLoc[i-1][j]&4)>0){
      staticWallLoc[i][j]=staticWallLoc[i][j]|1;
    }
}
```

You will also want to change your `[i++]` to `[i+1]`.

Comment: Thanks, I made a really really stupid mistake, I'm  just used to using -- and ++, im a first time programmer, so these stupid mistakes are seldom but, I still make them! XD
thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. Mistakes like these provide valuable experience. Now when you read a theoretical book you will at least have the benefit of having this memorable occasion to better understand the reasoning behind various programming practices, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Dude - why are you decrementing in the loop body the same variables you're using to control the loop counter?!?

Sounds like "one step forward, two steps back", doesn't it ;)?

SUGGESTION:

Run the debugger, single step through a few iterations, and carefully note what happens to "i" and "j".

How soon do you think either or both will reach "11" ;)?

Comment: +1, this is some messed up code.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you have statements like `if (i>0) {staticWallLoc[i--][j]...`. These are directly altering the loop index. So, when `i` is `1`, it is changed back to `0`. When the loop is incremented, it goes back to `1`, and then `0` again, creating an infinite loop.

Do you perhaps mean to use `staticWallLoc[i - 1][j]...`, etc. ? This gets the desired index without changing the loop index.

Answer (score 0):

rather than using i++ i-- etc in your code,  just use offsets  i-1 or i+1.

General rule of thumb: in for loops, don't mess with the for loop variables within the body.

(there are exceptions to the rule, but this doesn't look like an exceptional case)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the heck the contents of your array is it's hard to say.  Might it be because you're modifying the values of i and j on the fly with `--` and `++`?  Do you mean to be keeping those values constant and doing something like:

```
if((staticWallLoc[i+1][j]&1)>0){staticWallLoc[i][j]=staticWallLoc[i][j]|4;} // changed i++ to i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Once j reaches 10, it does not get incremented in the "if (j < 10)" section, but it gets decremented in the "if (j > 0)" section, so j will end the loop at 9, then get incremented back to 10 by the loop management. So you will have an infinite loop with i = -1/0 (since it gets decremented and incremented in the loop) and j = 9/10 (for the same reason).

Answer (score 0):

You do a j-- in the last if once j >=10. The loop will stuck at j==10.

It's not a very good idea to manipulate the loop variable :)