# Art & Science of Java Chapter 4, Exercise 8

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that does a countdown to liftoff, but using a while loop, instead of an for loop.

So far, all I succeed in doing is creating an infinite loop, even though I'm using the same basic principles as the for loop code.

```
import acm.program.*;



public class CountDownWhile extends ConsoleProgram {


    public void run() {
        int t = START;
        while (t >= 0); {
            println(t);
            t = t--;
            }
        println("Liftoff!");
        }

    private static final int START = 10;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two error in your code. And that's the reason you're getting an infinite loop

1.

```
while (t >= 0);
```

You shouldn't add a semi-colon after this line, because it is actually means a while loop with nothing in it.

2.

```
t = t--;
```

you can check this question to learn more about this syntax : [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

In short, the value of `t--` are still 10, so `t = t--` dose not change the value of t.

The loop should look like this:

```
while (t >= 0) {
    println(t);
    t--;
}
println("Liftoff!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the `;` after the while loop.   Try removing the `;`...

```
public void run() {
    int t = START;
    while (t >= 0); {  /// <------ Problem 1. Correct: while(t>=0)
        println(t);
        t = t--;       /// <------ Problem 2. Correct: t--;   
        }
    println("Liftoff!");
    }
```

and the second problem is

```
t=t--;
```

as the value of t remains unchanged.