# If y = 1 and y = y++, why when I print y is the value 1?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is x after “x = x++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

```
int y = 1;
y = y++;
System.out.println("Value Of y :"+y);
```

The output is 
Value Of y : 1

I am incrementing the y and assigning that to "y" again.
y++ hence first the value is used and then it increments the value.
Hence it assign the value and it gets incremented. So I thought the output would be 2.

```
int y = 1;
int x = y++;
System.out.println("Value Of x :"+x);
System.out.println("Value Of y :"+y);
```

The output is:
Value Of x : 1
Value Of y : 2

In this case it is working. I mean the way I thought is correct.

Can any one please explain to me why?