# post increment behaviour

Tags: java, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

i have small doubt.why the below code is printing value i=2.

```
int i=2;
i=i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

can someone please explain me what is happening in line no 2.

so there is no meaning here of doing ++ here?

Thanks

Comment: No need to assign the `i++` value back to `i`. `int i = 2; i++; System.out.println(i);`

Comment: ...or `int i = 2; System.out.println(++i);`

Comment: Same question posted recently.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033676/if-y-1-and-y-y-why-when-i-print-y-is-the-value-1

Comment: @MiljenMikic Incredible... 37 upvotes that one.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: On top of, it was posted few days ago (I wouldn't surprise if it was in 2009/2010).

Comment: @Nambari Yes, that's what really baffled me. Sometimes old questions slowly accumulate upvotes, but there seemed to be an incredible flurry of upvotes immediately after posting. WOW, it actually has **62** upvotes and 25 downvotes!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, it's nice brain teaser, but seen so many times before..

Comment: @MiljenMikic It doesn't work for me as a brain teaser, but I understand: for a question to get upvoted that many times it needs to tease the brains of the masses. BTW 162 upvotes on the answer, I mean really!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i=i++;
```

Because first the assignment happens, then the increment applies.

Something like:

first i gets 2, then ++ operation happens, but results won't be re-assigned to i, so i value will remain as 2.

Comment: After increment  is the value stored on the heap or stack? Is the incremented value lost unless stored in some variable again??

Comment: @Raghunandan: Assuming it is local variable, it will be stored on stack. It will stay in memory, but there is no way to refer/access it.

Comment: Thanks that cleared my doubt. +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @Raghunandan: Don't use post increment, you could do something like i += 1; (or) i=  i+1 etc.,

Comment: The explanation of this answer is WRONG. It is marked as correct answer which will mislead people who reached to this question. The correct answer is like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911791/231010

Answer (score 2):

`i = i++;` first evaluates the `i++` expression, which increments `i` and evaluates to the  value of `i` *prior* to the increment. Since you immediately assign to `i` this value, it resets the value of `i` so the increment appears to never have happened. `i = ++i;` would cause the other behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you are telling `i=i++;` you are telling the computer to assign i to i, and after that, increment i's value, but it will not affect i, because i's value is 2.

The correct way to do it should be `i=++i;` meaning, add 1 to i before assigning it to i, or you could simply use `i++;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for helping me in understanding the things which was of great value.

I found somewhere nice post on this.

I got the answer from the suggestion given by stackoverflow forum only but there was some clear explanation missing what I feel.

Miljen Mikic suggested link is not working and saying page not found.

Some Clear explanation given for problem below is

```
int a=2, b=2;
int c = a++/b++;
System.out.println(c);
```

disassembles to the following.

```
   0:iconst_2      ; [I]Push the constant 2 on the stack[/I]  
   1:istore_1      ; [I]Pop the stack into local variable 1 (a)[/I]  
   2:iconst_2      ; [I]Push the constant 2 on the stack, again[/I]  
   3:istore_2      ; [I]Pop the stack into local variable 2 (b)[/I]  
   4:iload_1       ; [I]Push the value of a on the stack[/I]  
   5:iinc1, 1  ; [I]Add 1 to local variable 1 (a)[/I]  
   8:iload_2       ; [I]Push the value of b on the stack[/I]  
   9:iinc2, 1  ; [I]Add 1 to local variable 2 (b)[/I]  
   12:idiv          ; [I]Pop two ints off the stack, divide, push result[/I]  
   13:istore_3      ; [I]Pop the stack into local variable 3 (c)[/I]  
   14:return
```

which help me understand much better.

Please add to this If I am wrong in my point.

Thanks for all your answers.