# What is the difference between x++ and ++x in Java

Tags: java, increment

> ### What is the difference between x++ and ++x in Java
>
> Can anybody please tell me the difference of the above by refering the below code,

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=10;
        int y;
        y=x++;  //Prints 11     10 
        System.out.println(x+"\t"+y)
    }
}

class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=10;
        int y;
        y=++x;  //Prints 11     11 
        System.out.println(x+"\t"+y)
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094872/799558

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not necessarily, if you don't know it's called *postincrement* and *preincrement*, respectively. Easy if you know. Still a duplicate, this has been asked many times.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You don't need to call it by name though. Just put i++ vs ++i in some search engine.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Actually its very easy, check this [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=difference+between+x%2B%2B+and+%2B%2Bx+java&oq=difference+between+x%2B%2B+and+%2B%2Bx+java&gs_l=hp.3...766.10380.0.10500.39.20.2.17.18.0.247.2664.0j18j1.19.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.r_6b-1uvjYI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.d2k&fp=2d067e3b3a7f4d22&biw=1280&bih=923)

Answer (score 3):

`y=x++` assigns x to y, then increments x.

`y=++x` increments x, and then assigns it to y.

Answer (score 2):

`++x` is the **pre-increment**. i.e., The value of x is first incremented and then assigned to x.

`x++` is **post increment**. i.e., the value of x is assigned first and then incremented.

```
y=x++;
```

is essentially same as

```
y =x;
x= x+1;
```

`y=++x;` is same as

```
y= (x+1);
```

Comment: @MichaelKjörling sorry, i dint get you. why would you reassign y to x??

Answer (score 0):

Pre and Post increment. Increment BEFORE assignment and increment AFTER assignment respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case (`x++`) Java first resolves the assignment issue and then increments `x`. In the other case (`++x`) Java first resolves the increment and then the assignment.
In the following code you will see the difference:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    y = 2 + x++;
    assertEquals(2, x);
    assertEquals(3, y);
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    y = 2 + ++x;
    assertEquals(2, x);
    assertEquals(4, y);
}
```

As you can see, `x` always will be incremented, but the difference is the order in which the expression is resolved.

Hope it would be useful!