# How to working of : x = x++?

Tags: java

Java Code below :

```
    int x = 10;
    while (x != 15){
       x = x++;
       System.out.println("Value X " + x);
    }
```

execute : endless Loop ? why ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Answer (score 2):

Because `x` will never change and always will be `10`. Read JLS.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but `x++` incrementes x **after** reading it so `x = x++` means `x = x`.
You should use `x = ++x` instead.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Becouse you assign the old value of `x` to `x` befor you increase the value!
Try this:

```
int x = 10;
while (x != 15){
   x++;
}
```

or

```
int x = 10;
while (x != 15){
   x = ++x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

x++; increments the value of x then returns the old value of x.

THEN x = (that number) executes, meaning the mutation x++ did of x is undone.

Answer (score 1):

The line `x = x++;` should be `x++;`

Answer (score 0):

Because `x = x++` will assign the result of the operation `x++` to `x`. What you want is only `x++;`, which increments the value of `x` by one.