# The difference between n++ and ++n at the end of a while loop? (ANSI C)

Tags: c, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

this is probably a dumb question but I just can't figure it out. It has to do with the differences between n++ and ++n (which I thought I understood but apparently not).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long algorithmA(int n);
long algorithmB(int n);

int main(){
    long A, B;
    A = B = 0;
    int n = 1;
    while(A >= B){
        A = algorithmA(n);
        B = algorithmB(n);
        n++;
    }
    printf("At n = %d, Algorithm A performs in %ld seconds & "
           "Algorithm B performs in %ld seconds.", n, A, B);

}

long algorithmA(int n){
    return pow(n,4) * 86400 * 4;
}

long algorithmB(int n){
    return pow(3,n);
}
```

Here you can probably tell I'm trying to see at what point Algorithm A outperforms Algorithm B. The functions and units of time were given to me in a homework problem.

Anyways, I always thought that the order of "++" would not matter at the end of a while loop. But if I put ++n instead of n++, I get the wrong answer. Can somebody explain why?

Edit: Well it WAS showing 24 with ++n and 25 with n++, but it must have been for another reason. Because I just checked now and there is no difference. Thanks for your patience and time guys, I just wish I knew what I did!

Comment: Not sure if a direct duplicate (different language) but I bet the problem is the same. [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java?rq=1).

Comment: @mlwn I think you got those backwards.

Comment: @Takendarkk lol.. just deleted it.. :)   mis typing..

Comment: When the operation stands alone, and its "result" is not used, there is no difference.  Only if the result is used (as in `myArray[n++]`) does it make a difference, and that difference is whether you effectively fetch the array element before incrementing or after.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between these, since the increment isn't used in an expression. Do you have output that shows otherwise?

Comment: (It should not make a difference in the above code.)

Comment: Hmm really weird, it must have been something else. I checked again and there was no difference. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between `n++` and `++n` is that `n++` yields the original value of `n`, and `++n` yields the value of `n` after it's been incremented.  Both have the side effect of modifying the value of `n` by incrementing it.

If the result is discarded, as it is in your code, there is no effective difference.

If your program is behaving differently depending on whether you write

```
n++;
```

or

```
++n;
```

it must be for some other reason.

In fact, when I compile and execute your program on my system, I get exactly the same output in both cases.  Adding newlines to the output format, I get:

```
At n = 25, Algorithm A performs in 114661785600 seconds &
Algorithm B performs in 282429536481 seconds.
```

You haven't told us what output you're getting.  Please update your question to show the output in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

If you increment without assignment, no difference.  However, in the following circumstances, there is:

```
int n = 1;
int x = n++; // x will be 1 and n will be 2
```

In this example, the statement gets executed prior to the increment.

```
int n = 1;
int x = ++n; // both x and n will be 2
```

However, in this example, increment occurs prior to the execution of the statement.

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix versions (++n) alter the variable and then pass along its value.
The postfix version (n++) pass along the current value and then alter the variable.