# Are these two loops equivalent: off-by-one

Tags: c++, loops, off-by-one

Are these two loops the same? For some reason the second loop is off-by-one and I cannot figure out why.

```cpp
while ( !b && ++n < WORD_COUNT ) b = mWords[n];
```

```cpp
n++;
while ( !b && n < WORD_COUNT ) {
    b = mWords[n];
    n++;
}
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705000/the-difference-between-n-and-n-at-the-end-of-a-while-loop-ansi-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the predicate `b` was not successful, then a logic short-circuit may apply in the first form and the final increment of `n` may be skipped.

In the second form, the increment happens before predicate `b` is evaluated, so `n` is off-by-one when the loop exits.