# What does someArray[--n] mean?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried googling this but Google doesn't handle "--n" well. I saw this in my professor's code:

```
f[--n];
f[n++];
```

where f is an array of double values.

My guess is that it returns the value of f[n] before reducing (or adding) to n.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: They are not the same. The first is a pre-decrement and the second is a post-increment.

Comment: --n means "decrement the value of n then find the element at that index" 

n++ means "find the element at index n, then increment n"

Comment: Your guess would be correct for the latter example, incorrect for the former example.  In any case, **try it**.  That is the best way to learn anything.

Comment: Almost-dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094872/2069350

Comment: *"I saw this in my professor's code"* (Shouldn't you ask your professor then? It is their code.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f[--n];` means :

```
n = n -1;
f[n];
```

`f[n++];` means :

```
f[n];
n = n + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a type of operator called a pre-decrement, and it's part of a family of 4 operators (see [table of java operators](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html))

For an integer-type variable called n:

1. post-increment `n++` is the equivalent of `n = n + 1`, the 'post' part means that if you see it in a line of code (ex. `foo(n++);`) then the line of code will be called Before n is incremented.
2. pre-increment `++n` is also the same as `n = n + 1` but it occurs Before the line of code it belongs in has been run.
3. post-decrement `n--` is the equivalent of `n = n - 1` and occurs After the current line of code has been run
4. pre-decrement `--n` is the equivalent of `n = n - 1` and occurs Before the current line of code has been run

Example of post vs pre decrement:

```
int n = 5;

System.out.println(n--); //This prints 5
System.out.println(n); //This prints 4

System.out.println(--n); //This prints 3
System.out.println(n); //this prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look it up under predecrement (--n) or postincrement (n++). 
It works like this:

- f[--n]: first n is reduced by 1 then the value of f[n] (this is already the reduced n) is returned
- f[n++]: first the value of f[n] is returned then n is increased by 1

Example:

f {1,3,5}
n=1;

- f[--n] returns 1
- f[n++] returns 3

Comment: wouldn't `f[n++]` return 3?

Comment: @ochi: oops my mistake you are right of course! i'll edit my answer. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
f[--n];
f[n++];
```

Is the same as

```
n--;
f[n];
f[n];
n++;
```

Comment: @uni it's only a heuristic. Sometimes it's wrong :)