# Is there a diffence between x++ and ++x in memory? Is relative about language?

Tags: memory

Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in memory? is relative about programming language?

Comment: What do you mean by "in memory"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Comment: Hmm. Java works with an operand stack. So there will be differences in the values in the operand stack - but is that what you mean at all?

Comment: I know the result. one is a preincrement,another is a postincrement.  when I using the expression, what will memory do ?

Comment: It's different everywhere. Even within java because it depends on whether is actually uses the operand stack or simply optimizes the difference away. E.g. a `for(..; i++)` loop is identical to a `for(..; ++i)` loop and the compiler / runtime will make the most efficient version out of it that behaves according to your specification.

Answer (score 1):

The only way memory is affected is in the difference of moments when the value is modified. As you probably know, ++x makes the increment before the processing, whereas x++ makes the increment after the processing.

Comment: whether using x++ ,memory will copy the value of x to another memory area,then it make a increment. while using ++x, it make a increment directly.  If so, ++x is more effective than x++?