# Java: iterate through two arrays and using correct values

Tags: java, list, indexing, null

Given 2 int arrays, `a` and `b`, return a new array length 2 containing, as much as will fit, the elements from `a` followed by the elements from `b`. The arrays may be any length, including 0, but there will be 2 or more elements available between the 2 arrays.

I'm wondering how to use `a !=`, and `null.` This is the first question I've used it in and I'm having a few errors.
So my logic was to iterate through list `a`, until a `null` point, then go onto list `b`.

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
      int[] answer = new int[2];
      for(int x = 0; x <= 1; x++){
          if(a[x] != null)
              answer[x] = a[x];
          else if (b[x != null]){
              answer[x] = b[x];
          }
      }

}
```

Something like this. Any tips on how to check for emptiness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (b[x != null]){
```

Is not a valid statement, this will cause an error because `(x != null) = true` so is the same as  `else if (b[true]){` which does not make much sense.

Also, an empty `array` position of `int` will never be `null` but zero `0` instead.

Use this instead:

```
else if (b[x] != 0){
```

---

One more thing: as title says, use `List` to instead of `array` to have a variable number of elements:

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
      List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(int x = 0; x <= 1; x++){    
          if(a[x] != 0) {             
              answers.add(a[x]);
          } else if (b[x] != 0) {
              answers.add(b[x]);
          }
      }
}
```

NOTES:

- use `answers` instead of `answer`, is better name for a `List` with multiple elements.
- take as usual to use ALWAYS `{` even if the statements inside are just one line
- your function is not valid since does not include `return answer`

---

## EDIT

> Sorry about the title, my mistake. It is arrays

In this case, just remember **arrays are not resizeable**, so in the moment of creating the array check maximum size:

```
int maxSize = a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length;
int[] answer = new int[maxSize];
```

> NOTE: you can use this variable in your loop to check max number...

---

## EDIT2

> An empty array position is represented by a 0? What about the example make2({}, {1, 2}) → {1, 2}, will a[0] != 0 skip it? because index 0 doesn't exist?

1. you cannot use `make2({}, {1, 2})`, not a valid statement in this case. To simulate this do:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[2];
        int b[] = new int[2];
        b[0] = 1;
        b[1] = 2;
        make2(a,b);
        // if you want to see the output:
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(make2(a,b)));
   }
   ```
2. It won't skip it, it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, in this case, you must make you function failsafe, for this, just check lenghts before accessing the element to assert it will exist:

   ```
   public static int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
         int[] answer = new int[2];
         for(int x = 0; x <= 1; x++){
             if(a.length >= x && a[x] != 0) { 
                 answer[x] = a[x];
             } else if (b.length >= x && b[x] != 0){
                 answer[x] = b[x];
             }
             // optional
             else {
                 answer[x] = -1; // this tells you there's no valid element!
             }
         }
         return answer;
   }
   ```

---

## SOLUTION:

> http://www.codingbat.com/prob/p143461 Here is a url to the question :D

Ok, you were missing the examples, all would be much clearer...  This code pass all tests.

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int[] answer = new int[2];       // create the array to fill
  int y = 0;                       // create a variable to check SECOND array position
  for(int x = 0; x <= 1; x++){     // make 2 iterations
      if(a.length > x) {           // if ARRAY a has a possible value at POSITION x
          answer[x] = a[x];        // put this value into answer
      } else if (b.length > y){    // if ARRAY a does not have possible value at POSITION x, 
                                   // check if ARRAY b has some possible value at POSITION y 
                                   // (remember y is the variable that keeps position of ARRAY b)
          answer[x] = b[y++];      // put b value at answer
      }
  }
  return answer;                   // return answer
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the title, my mistake. It is arrays.

Comment: actually using list or not to store `answers` is not important, use arrays but check my edit and tell me if it works for you ;)

Comment: An empty array position is represented by a 0? What about the example make2({}, {1, 2}) → {1, 2}, will a[0] != 0 skip it? because index 0 doesn't exist?

Comment: nope, this is not an empty position, is an empty array with no positions at all wil throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: also, you cannot call  `make2({}, {1, 2})` is not a valid expression in this case

Comment: @NewtoJava please check EDIT2, and don't hesitate to ask further explanations if necessary

Comment: If you're interested, I still couldn't get it working so I made spaghetti code and the answer is;  public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int[] answer = new int[2];
  if(a.length == 0)
   return b;
  else if(b.length == 0){
   answer[0] = a[0];
   answer[1] = a[1];
  }
  else if (a.length == 1){
   answer[0] = a[0];
   answer[1] = b[0];
  }
  else if (a.length >= 2){
   answer[0] = a[0];
   answer[1] = a[1];
  }
  return answer;
   
 }

Comment: actually the code is not correct, you can return a in the second case, but, what errors you get with the code in `EDIT2`???

Comment: check the solution in my answer ;)

Comment: I havent used y++ without being in a for loop like x++ on line 4, does it use the value of 0 in the indexing and then increase it to 1?, your code if something I wouldn't have thought of at my earn learning of java. Well written. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `answer[x] = b[y++];` uses actual `y` value **AND** after, increases `y` in `1`. Take a look to [**this question for clarification**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java), is equivalent to this 2 lines: `answer[x] = b[y]; y = y + 1;`

Comment: Could you possibly explain your pathway of thinking to create this code? When you saw the question what were your precautions to prevent over indexing.

Comment: Oh I see, you were abusing the idea that the length is always higher than the indexs. So you were comparing length and index, so to find an available index. The length must be higher than the index, and you were using that idea to check if the index was available.

Comment: exactly, but keep in mind you need 2 indexes: `x` index that is used for array `a` and array `answer` **AND** `y` index, that will be used **ONLY IF NECESSARY** to check array `b`. 

Check also new comments in the **SOLUTION**, hope they clarify

Comment: Hi @NewtoJava as this is your first question, you must know if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check array if it string but your array is int. so you can use the following example

```
int arr[] = null;
if (arr != null) {
  System.out.println("array is null");
}


arr = new int[0];
if (arr.length != 0) {
  System.out.println("array is empty");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a few questions, before I suggest you some alternatives. 1. why are  you declaring  int[] answer = new int[2]; when question says 2 or more elements.

You should use :

```
List<int> stockList = new ArrayList<int>();

if(a[x] != null)
    stockList.add(a[x]);
else if (b[x] != null){
    stockList.add(b[x]);
}

int[] stockArr = new int[stockList.size()];
stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);
```

Comment: Because the question says return a new array of length 2.

Comment: @NewtoJava, your question said, " but there will be 2 or more elements available between the 2 arrays." thus I am suggesting a list