# x += ++x equivalent to x = 2x+1 : Why?

Tags: java

This question is just curiosity : I was wondering what would be the value of some `int x` after the line `x += ++x`
So I tried that :

```
int x=10;
x+=++x;
System.out.println(x);
```

And it printed out :

```
21
```

After some tests with other values, it seems to be equivalent to x=2x+1. Why ? Is this line interpreted by the compiler as a byte operation ? (By the way, x += x++ seems to be equivalent to x=2x).

I don't think it's something I'd ever use in a project, but I'm curious to know why I get this result.

Thanks for any explanation or hint

EDIT : First of all, thanks for your answers

I knew how the `+=` operator works, as well as the `x++` and `++x`, but for some reason the (completely logic and obvious) result seemed strange to me
I should probably have thought it through, sorry for your time !

Comment: Well, you do just that. x + x + 1, which is 2x + 1

Comment: `x+=++x;` -> `x = x + ++x;` where `++x` returns increased value.

Comment: Algebra?  take away the ++ and you get x+=x === 2x the ++ adds the one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way it is calculated is

- Step 1: x = x + ++x
- Step 2: It become x = 10 + (incremented x) 11
- Step 3: Final result stored in x i.e. 21

Here is the proof:

I created a MainClass as below:

```
public class MainClass{
public static void main(String...s){
int x = 10;
x += ++x;
}
}
```

and then checked the bytecode using `javap -c MainClass`

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: bipush        10     // push 10 onto stack
       2: istore_1             // store 10 in local variable 1
       3: iload_1              // load local variable 1 (now 10) back to stack
       4: iinc          1, 1   //increment local variable 1 by 1
       7: iload_1              // load local variable 1  (now 11) back to stack
       8: iadd                 // add top 2 variable on stack ( 10 and 11)
       9: istore_1             // store 21 to local variable 1
      10: return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its about operator precedence and how `++x` and `x++` are evaluated and used. with `++x`, the value of `x` is incremented and then used so `++x` becomes `11` and this `x += ++x` becomes `21` which is `10 + 11`

However `x++` says `x` is used and then its value is incremented

so `x+= x++` will mean `10 + 10` i.e `20`

Answer (score 0):

```
int x=10;
x+=++x;
System.out.println(x);
```

`x + = ++x` is evaluated in the compiler to `x = x + ++x` => `x = 10 + ++x` => `x = 10 + 11` => `x = 21`

Answer (score 0):

See here:-

```
x+=++x; this expression will be executed like x=x+(x+1) so x = 10 + 11
```

hence x = 21;

You need to understand about pre-increment(++x) and post-increment (x++). see below

```
 int x = 10;
 if (x++ == 10 )
     System.out.println( "X is equal to 10");// this statement will print
```

in the above if condition it will execute as true because first it will compare as is 10 == 10 and then x will be incremented by one and x will become 11.

Now see below:-

```
   if (++x == 10 )
     System.out.println( "X is equal to 10");// this will not print if condition will tern false
```

In the above if condition x will be pre-incremented so x will become 11 and then a comparison will be done whether 11 == 10 hence if condition will failed.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

`++x` will return value of `(x+1)`, and `x` value will be increased by one too.

`x++` will return value of `(x)`, and `x` value will be increased by one too.

so

`x+=++x` is the same `x=x+(x+1)`, which is equivalent to `x=2*x+1`

`x+=++x` is the same as `x=x+(x)`, which is equivalent to `x=2*x`

Answer (score 0):

.....++x: first calculate x=x+1, then use x for comparing or calculating the actual task
.....x++: first compare / calculate actual task, after that calculate x=x+1