# i++ in the map method of java-stream

Tags: java, java-stream

In the code, I want to modify variable `i` by `map()` method:

```
Integer[] seq = {1, 3, 4, 1, 8, 11};

List<Integer> seqInt = Arrays.asList(seq);
List<Integer> seqFiltered = seqInt.stream().filter(i -> i%2!=0)
                                      .map(i -> i++)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(seqFiltered);
```

However, it outputs `[1, 3, 1, 11]` instead of `[2, 4, 2, 12]` which could be obtained from `map(i -> i+1)`

Comment: In addition to nullpointer's answer for more details: [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Just make use of the pre-increment instead of post-increment operator.

```
List<Integer> seqFiltered = seqInt.stream()
                                  .filter(i -> i%2!=0)
                                  .map(i -> ++i)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

also, you can make use of the `Arrays.stream` to use the Integer array as a stream

```
List<Integer> seqFiltered = Arrays.stream(seq)
                                  .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
                                  .map(i -> ++i)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It would be more intuitive (in my opinion) to use `map(i -> i + 1)` instead, especially as `i` is discarded, so the side-effect of the pre-increment operator (increasing `i` as well) is not used at all