# Why does the following code work? I was hoping it would produce an error but it dosen't

Tags: java

What will be the value of x in following code:

```
int x=15; 
x %= x++ + +x - 3
```

Please explain why.

Why doesn't it give syntax error for `+x` or the extra `+` before it?

Comment: if you look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html  the  Syntax of Java was designed this way. While disputable (especially more irritating examples)  - this is simple the way the language was created.

Answer (score 1):

```
x %= (x++) + (+x) - 3;
```

The `x++` is called postincrement. [You can check this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)
The `+x` is just a sign operator.

So your statement will evaluate to:

```
x %= (15) + (+16) - 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your code into parts like this to see how does it works:

```
    int x = 15; 
    int y = x++ + +x;
    System.out.println(y);  //result: 31 (x = 15, then incremation so it is 15 + 16)
    System.out.println(x);  //result: 16 because of previous incrementation
    y = y - 3;
    System.out.println(y);  //result: 31 - 3 = 28
    x %= y;
    System.out.println(x);  //result: 16 % 28 = 16
```

Comment: No matter how many + or - you use between this 2 numbers if the number of '-' are even then sum will be performed otherwise subtraction

Comment: Because addition and subtraction has the same priority so it goes from left to right. So + + + gives you + then is minut and + - 3 gives you negative number. It means that '-' negative number gives you positive.  x=15 + + + - (+ (- 3));

Comment: one may argue(I don't but for the sake of the challenge) an infix operator needs two operands and an operand has at most one sign operator.  And well other languages do work differently(and also correct).