# Why does the JS increment shorthand not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a very simple script but do not understand why one syntax isn't working over the other.

The function is to simply increment any number by one.

This one does not work

```
function plusOne(x) {
  return x++;
}
```

but this one does.

```
function plusOne(x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

What am I not understanding??

Comment: you need to use `return ++x;`

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-back-to-basics-prefix-vs-postfix-8da5256223d2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java

Comment: Its called `unary +` operator

Comment: wow I had no clue there was a post and pre increment operation. Thanks all

Comment: @CuongVo: As a rule, you want to default to pre-increment, only using post-increment when you *want* the "return old value, increment variable" behavior. Aside from being somewhat more intuitive to increment and return the incremented value, in some language (e.g. C++) with some types (e.g. non-primitive types), there is a significant performance penalty for using post-increment (it has to copy the underlying object and return it after incrementing, rather than just modifying the underlying object in place and returning a reference to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Increment (++)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it **returns the value before incrementing**

You should use

```
function plusOne(x) {
  return ++x;
}
```

Comment: You beat me on this one...