# Parameters on call recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion to search for all the files and their sub-files in a folder. But I want to add indentation to make the output more beautiful. I added an int variable to the variable of the function to indicate how many indents are needed.This is the final code for success.

```
public void seekFile(File file, int tab) {
    File [] files=file.listFiles();
    assert files != null;
    for (File file1 : files) {
        if (file1.isFile()){
            for(int i = 0; i< tab; i++)
                System.out.print("|\t");
            System.out.println(file1.getName());
        }else {
            for(int i = 0; i< tab; i++)
                System.out.print("|\t");
            System.out.println(file1.getName());
            int index = tab+1;
            seekFile(file1,index);
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I used `seekFile(file1, ++tab)` to do a recursion, but the indentation I got was all wrong, and the output was accurate after I swapped out the `tab`. Why is that?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `++tab` and `tab + 1`?

Comment: Maybe it's an address question? I'll find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++tab` does two things:

- evaluates to the value of "1 more than 'the value of `tab`'"
- changes the value of `tab` to the above value

([It actually does a lot more things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12111301/5133585), but for the purpose of understanding the code in the question, just those two is enough)

`tab + 1` does one thing:

- evaluates to the value of "1 more than 'the value of `tab`'"

`tab + 1` does not change the value of `tab`.

This is crucial, because you do not want `tab` to change within each recursive call. Every iteration of the `for (File file1 : files)` loop should use the same `tab`, because each iteration prints out a file/directory *in the same directory*. It is only when you call the `seekFile`, that you will use a higher `tab` number.

If you use `++tab`, and you encounter a directory, `tab` will be incremented, and every *sibling* file/directory after that will have more indentation than it should.

If you use `tab + 1`, The `tab` for the current call doesn't change.

In both cases, the value of "1 more than 'the value of `tab`'" is passed to the next recursive call of `seekFile`, and a new stack frame is created and pushed onto the call stack. Each stack frame has its own `tab` variable, which is why passing `tab + 1` to the new call doesn't affect the `tab` variable in the current call.